# How to make a style color global?

Tags: html, css

I'm sure that this question is answered somewhere, but I can't find it, I'm not even sure how to describe the question correctly

I looking for  some way put the color code part in like css, so it becomes global, so I can change all instances can be changed at once.

It's little hard to see the transparent links otherwise..

```
<a href="#" style="color: rgb(255,0,0,0)" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxxxxxxxxxx </a> </span></p>
```

Maybe it's solved by class?

Something like:

```
<a href="#" style=.color1 onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxxxxxxxxxx
My personal knowledge about css is, maybe, 1%..
```

Comment: It's not possible with plain CSS, but you can use something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide) to define variables.

Comment: Use a class defined in a stylesheet instead of inlining your styles

Comment: Thats precisely why "classes" are used, that is if your not fine with using any CSS preprocessors like SASS or LESS.

Comment: by global, do you mean every `<a>` tag? what do you mean?

Comment: Not all, only just these ones... And I have buy idea how to use classes..

Comment: @JoBe Then learn how to.

Comment: @APAD1 I want to get this straight--you're saying "plain old CSS" has no way to define rules that apply to multiple elements?

Comment: You can define a class and apply that class to any elements you want treated with those CSS rules as @j08691 recommends.

Comment: not `style=.color1` but `class="color1"`.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I tried Nikhil Nanjappa's suggestion, and it worked without any problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.myClass {
  color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xx</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxx</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxx</a>
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxxx</a>
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxx</a>
```

Use a `class` with defined styles & give that class name to the elements you want to target(`class="myClass"` in this example). Like so:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xx</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxx</a>
<a href="#" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxx</a>
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxxx</a>
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxx</a>
```

In your CSS file define the class you used like so

**CSS**

```
.myClass {
  color: rgb(255,0,0); // change only this to affect all with this class name
}
```

> Note: Ideally `rgb` should have only 3 parameters representing **red, green, blue**`(255, 0, 0)` respectively and `rgba` should have 4 parameters representing **red, green, blue, alpha**`(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`. The last parameter alpha represents transparency. You can use any of your choice.

In your question, you have mentioned `color: rgb(255,0,0,0)`. This is incorrect because you are using `rgb` function with 4 parameters(not 3). This will not give you the desired `red` color your looking for. `color: rgb(255, 0, 0)` is correct.

Comment: Ok, strange, I used your example, and it worked perfectly, BUT I did the test with only rgb, not rgba, yet it still worked!

Comment: Yes, it will work with both `rgb` and `rgba` but you just need to know how many parameters each of these functions take. That's what the info was about. Also I guess you are trying to get the color `red`, yes ?

Comment: I have updated the note to give a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you want **ALL of the links in your project** to have a specific color simple add to your stylesheet:

```
a {
  color: red;
}
```

It is probably **BETTER** in most cases to add a class like:

```
<a href="#" class="my_link" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxxxxxxxxxx </a> </span></p>
```

then in your stylesheet do:

```
.my_link {
  color: red;
}
```

which will **only change the color of that particular link or any other specific element that you add the `my_link` class to**.

See **@Michael Dawn's** answer of how to add a stylesheet to your project:

Create a file named `my_styles.css` & add the css examples there.

Add a link in the `<head>` of your html file like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_styles.css">`

This allows your html file to work with your css file/stylesheet.

Comment: It's probably better to use a class instead.

Comment: well yeah, but this person wants to change an element globally (I take that to mean ALL links)... why would you need a class?

Comment: Ok, well I know 5% of css, but 0% of classes.

Comment: Do you have any sylesheets / .css folders in your project?

Comment: Yes, I do,  but another question, how do I do to select the correct answer here, if there are two that are correct?

Comment: you select whichever seems to answer every point of your question.  Whichever seems more thorough and most likely to help others... (my opinion I guess)... : )  You can upvote multiple answers though.

Comment: Also, you should check out a quick CSS tutorial (codecademy or likewise).  It's very easy to learn the basics.  : )

Comment: @JoBe If you know 0% of classes, then  you also know 0% of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Write your css codes in a separate file with extension ".css" and then include it to you page like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

then you easily edit your css codes and the change will be affected by all classes of the same name and ids.
Or if you want it to be more easier you can use sass.

You can include your styles like:

```
 <div class="header">...</div>
```

and so on...

Comment: What about this would be made easier with SASS?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use sass. You can find tutorial tutorialspoint.com. Examples here will not help you in understanding sass

Comment: Come on, just a little hint as to how you would use SASS here??? Please?

Comment: Sass is css preprocessor. You write style and compile it to affect your css file.
The syntax for sass is a bit different from normal css

     .class
        :color red
        :background white

indentation is important just like python

Comment: You have completely failed to show how it is "more easier" if I use SASS. Are you saying it is more easier because I can worry about indentation instead of worrying about curly brackets? Didn't you leave out of your "more easier" calculation the need to add a new step to my build pipeline?

Comment: No am saying indentaton cause you want me to show you example. Sass is easier cause it make you manage your css faster, like a templating or as you mentioned global.
If you have a style .classDiv in multiple css file, you can use sass to update their styles dynamically. When you write sass style and compiles it, it affects your css styles and you dont need to go through thousands of lines of css styles to make individual changes.

Comment: Am new to sass but i know its way better to manage css style with

Comment: If you're new to SASS, I'd recommend keeping your opinions about it to yourself for the time being. It's an ancient technology which has been superseded by different and better CSS pre-processor approaches.

Comment: @torazaburo superseded by what? Stylus or even LESS? I think Sass with the SCSS styleset is de facto standard. Just take a look at state-of-the art projects (build generator) like jHipster or vue-cli. They all use Sass.

Comment: @torazaburo i just recommended and it was for the OP to not want my recommendation. Down voting me wasnt a rational thing to do but is cool, i understand

Comment: @ssc-hrep Superseded by modern frameworks like postcss.

Answer (score 0):

Put this piece of code inside  tag:

```
<style>
  body { 
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Isn't that sort of like the default?